# get_the_title() displays post or product title instead of page title

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an issue with displaying title in header. When I use functions like get_queried_object_id() happens same thing and I can't spot where the problem is.
This is my code where I try to display title.

```
<?php
$page_id = get_queried_object_id();
  ?>

  <div id="logo_section" class="row w-100 h-25  container-fluid justify-content-end p-0 mx-0">
    
  <?php 
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page_id ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); 
?>
<div class="jumbotron text-center section w-100 my-auto mr-0  " style="background-size:100% auto; background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position:center right; background-image: url('<?php echo $image[0]; ?>')">

          <h1 class="display-1 mt-5"><?php echo get_the_title($page_id)  ?></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well.. which title are you trying to display?

Comment: Because `get_queried_object_id` will on posts and pages, return the post or page id - on category pages, it will return the term_id, on author archive pages it will return the user ID. So I am guessing that your are going about your task wrong

Comment: I'd like to display a page title. in example I try to name my shop page in woocommerce and instead of page title I get title od first product.
P.S. Also I don't want default name "shop" to be displayed as in case of using the_title()

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the the_title()  function in your header it should work for you. because get_the_title only work within the loop and the_title() work out of loop as well.